# Replace Rows with Smaller Values than Row's Before it with Interpolated Values

Tags: r

I have integer variables that are a function of time. However, there are errors where a value decreases the day after and this is due to human error. I.E.

```
Date           Cases
2020-03-03      24
2020-03-02      21
2020-03-01      23
```

In 'Cases', 21 is an error. How can I replace values in my columns that are less than the rows before them with an interpolated value?

Comment: Should the value in `Cases` be 24 or 23?

Comment: It can be 23 or 24, just that since it's less than 23, it is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option with `case_when` in `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
     mutate(Cases = case_when(Cases - lag(Cases, 
       default = first(Cases)) < 0 ~ lag(Cases), TRUE ~ Cases))
#        Date Cases
#1 2020-03-03    24
#2 2020-03-02    24
#3 2020-03-01    23
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Date = c("2020-03-03", "2020-03-02", "2020-03-01"
), Cases = c(24L, 21L, 23L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Answer (score 3):

You could try

```
wrong <- c(0, diff(df$Cases)) < 0
df$Cases[wrong] <- df$Cases[which(wrong) - 1]
```

Result:

```r
df
#>         Date Cases
#> 1 2020-03-03    24
#> 2 2020-03-02    24
#> 3 2020-03-01    23
```

Comment: Still Cases in row #3 needs to be interpolated because it is less than 24. Shouldn't the whole code be in a loop?

Comment: @ahb65 Maybe. The question is a little unclear now that I look at it again. I think my solution works for the problem as described rather than the problem as demonstrated. But if done as a loop it would just be `for(i in seq_along(df$Cases)[-1]) if(df$Cases[i] < df$Cases[i - 1]) df$Cases[i] <- df$Cases[i - 1]`

Answer (score 0):

With interpolation:

```
df$Date[c(0, diff(df$Cases)) < 0] <- NA
df$Date <- as.POSIXct(zoo::na.approx(df$Date), origin = "1970-01-01")
```

Or if you want to interpolate Cases:

```
df$Cases[c(0, diff(df$Cases)) < 0] <- NA
df$Cases <- zoo::na.approx(df$Cases)
```